# Extracting null values with .reduceRegions() in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am extracting values from a Feature Collection over the MODIS Terra NDSI image collection using reduceRegions. I commented out the .filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null)) because I do want the null values. However, when I do, only some of the points have mean (the NDSI value) has a property. Do I need to add the mean value as it's own property in order to also extract null values?

I tried this: [Google Earth Engine - add label to feature collection table/CSV](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349948/google-earth-engine-add-label-to-feature-collection-table-csv) and: [GEE check only one sentinel tile instead of checking all of them when the featurecollection is in many tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358825/gee-check-only-one-sentinel-tile-instead-of-checking-all-of-them-when-the-featur/358878#358878)  apporaches but no luck.

I am using a sample feature collection to make debugging easier. Below is the code:

```
var features = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(30.01, 59.80, 30.59, 60.15), {name: 'Voronoi'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-73.96, 40.781), {name: 'Thiessen'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(6.4806, 50.8012), {name: 'Dirichlet'})
];

var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection(features);
print('fromList',fromList);


var MOD10A1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-05-30'))
                  .select(['NDSI_Snow_Cover']);

var results = MOD10A1.map(function(image) {
    return image.reduceRegions({
      collection: fromList, 
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      scale: 30 
    })//.filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null)) //** i think this is why I was getting weird values for the GEE extraction
      .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('imageId', image.date());
    });
}).flatten()

print(results)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: results,
  description: 'results', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between a null value in a feature and no value.  If you want an "empty" property in the export where there was no result from the reduceRegions, then you can map over the results and add a default value.  This is probably easiest by converting to a dictionary first and using combine with overwrite=false.

```
.map(function(f) {
  f = f.set(f.toDictionary().combine({mean: -1}, false))
  return f.set('imageId', image.date());
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the script with your code. However, the new table now has the value -1 for all values (not just the empty values). Is there a way to have the values -1 for only empty values?

Comment: I see the problem.  The overwrite option is inside the dictionary of values, not being used as an option.  Use this instead:        
    f = f.set(f.toDictionary().combine({mean: -1}, false))

Comment: that fixed it, thanks!